# Synchronization report for uncontained objects across each of the replicas in HAG

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, high-availability

I have seen [How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992) , [Synchronize Availability Group Logins and Jobs](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/synchronize-availability-group-logins-and-jobs/) and [SQL Server 2012 Availability Group Add-in](https://www.sqlskills.com/free-tools/sql-server-2012-availability-group-add-in/) to synchronize unconstrained objects between replica. There are a several more articles about "how to do it". What I could not find is a script to just report (not sync) the objects that are not in sync.

Comment: AFAIK you won't find one either - maybe you can make one and give it to the community :)

Comment: I second that, I have used some powershell tools and SQL Admin Toolset from IDERA but there is not one great solution that shows everything.